# Manage Cancel Axios in useEffect with conditional call API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, axios

I have two button that show different content (Message and Announcement)

let say on initial mount call an API to get list of `Message`, before user get a response from API, user `press` `Announcement` button to get list of `Announcement`.

here i want to cancel API call of `Message`, and call `Announcement` API,

i've tried this code but no luck:

```
import React from 'react';
import { ActivityIndicator, Dimensions, Text, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native';
import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
import AxiosHTTP from '../../../Component/AxiosHTTP';

const {width, height} = Dimensions.get('window')

export default Notification = (props)=>{
  const [data, setData] = React.useState(null)
  const [activeIndex, setIndex] = React.useState(props.activeIndex || 0)
  const source = React.useRef(null)

  /**
  * List function to handling component
  */

  React.useEffect(()=>{
    setData(null)
    source.current = axios.CancelToken.source()
    if(activeIndex == 0){
      AxiosHTTP.get('http://httpstat.us/200?sleep=4000', {cancelToken: source.token})
      .then(res=>{
        setData(JSON.stringify(res.data))
      })
    } else {
      AxiosHTTP.get('http://httpstat.us/200?sleep=4000', {cancelToken: source.token})
      .then(res=>{
        setData(JSON.stringify(res.data)+' Else')
      })
    }
  }, [activeIndex])

  function handleChangeTab(ind){
    source.current?.cancel && source.current.cancel('GANTI TAB')
    setIndex(ind)
  }

  /**
  * List function to render component
  */

  function listTab(){
    const showTab = ['Message', 'Announce'].map((el, ind)=>
      <TouchableOpacity key={ind.toString()} onPress={()=>handleChangeTab(ind)} style={{marginRight:8}}>
        <View>
          <Text>{el}</Text>
          {ind == activeIndex && <View style={{height:2, width:20, backgroundColor:'red', alignSelf:'center'}} />}
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    )
    return(
      <View style={{flexDirection:'row', marginBottom:14}}>
        {showTab}
      </View>
    )
  }

  /**
  * End list function to render component
  */

  return(
    <SafeAreaView style={{flex:1}}>
      {listTab()}
      {data == null
        ? <ActivityIndicator/>
        : <Text>{data}</Text>
      }
    </SafeAreaView>
  )
}
```

On `useEffect` i've condition to call API depend on `activeIndex`, but the cancel not fired in `handleChangeTab` in case axios still fetching old URL.

Can someone guide me how to properly cancel axios on above case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a local token inside the effect, and cancel it in the cleanup callback:

```
React.useEffect(()=>{
    setData(null)
    const source = axios.CancelToken.source()
    if(activeIndex == 0){
      AxiosHTTP.get('http://httpstat.us/200?sleep=4000', {cancelToken: source.token})
      .then(res=>{
        setData(JSON.stringify(res.data))
      })
    } else {
      AxiosHTTP.get('http://httpstat.us/200?sleep=4000', {cancelToken: source.token})
      .then(res=>{
        setData(JSON.stringify(res.data)+' Else')
      })
    }

    return ()=> source.cancel() // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
  }, [activeIndex])
```

Or you can use custom hooks that support cancellable async routines out of the box ([Autocancellable fetch demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/use-async-effect-fetch-tiny-ui-states-g5qd7?file=/src/TestComponent.js)):

```
import React from "react";
import { useAsyncEffect } from "use-async-effect2";
import cpAxios from "cp-axios";

/*
 Notice: the related network request will also be aborted
 Checkout your network console
 */

function TestComponent(props) {
  const [cancel, done, result, err] = useAsyncEffect(
    function* () {
      return (yield cpAxios(props.url).timeout(props.timeout)).data;
    },
    { states: true, deps: [props.url] }
  );

  return (
    <div className="component">
      <div className="caption">useAsyncEffect demo:</div>
      <div>
        {done ? (err ? err.toString() : JSON.stringify(result)) : "loading..."}
      </div>
      <button className="btn btn-warning" onClick={cancel} disabled={done}>
        Cancel async effect
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Return inside useEffect only for unmount component, since my screen still mounting but conditionally show screen return wouldn't work

Comment: Nope. The cleanup function executed on unmount or when one of its dependencies changes. Check out the demo https://codesandbox.io/s/use-async-effect-fetch-tiny-ui-states-forked-vtxo0?file=/src/TestComponent.js  Or if you want to cancel the request automatically you can use a custom hooks library - see the demo https://codesandbox.io/s/use-async-effect-fetch-tiny-ui-states-g5qd7?file=/src/TestComponent.js

Comment: i didn't know if return()=>{} still run on dependencies changes, thank you for great explanation :)

Answer (score 1):

You're storing *axios source object* in `source.current`, so the token is in `source.current.token`.

Change your code from:
`{cancelToken: source.token}`
to `{cancelToken: source.current.token}`